# How to change date format in reactjs like (17-Jun-2022)

Tags: reactjs, laravel

MY CODE

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        setOpeningdate(new Date().toDateString());
    }, 1000)
});
```

Code Output : Fri Jun 17 2022

But I Want : 17-Jun-2022

Comment: use moment js , try .. moment(new Date().toDateString()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. You can easily change it into any date format you prefer.

```
import moment from 'moment';
const date = moment(new Date().toDateString()).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

If you don't want to use any library, you can also change the format as below.

```
function formatDate() {
  const date = new Date().toDateString().split(" ");  
  return date[2] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[3]
}

.....

 useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        setOpeningdate(formatDate());
    }, 1000)
});
```